# "Could not find metadata" error when loading TSQLConnection params from INI file

Tags: delphi

I have the following code below. I perform the connection via `.ini` file:

```
try
  sqlConexao.LoadParamsFromIniFile('Config.ini');
  sqlConexao.Connected:=True;
except
  on E:Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
 end;
```

Within the IDE, I normally connect to the database, see video:

https://www.screencast.com/t/llh4K8hBma

However, via the `.ini` file, the following error occurs:

> Could not find metadata: TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory; package: DbxOracleDriver260.bpl. Add DBXDynalink to your uses.

Watch the error video:

https://www.screencast.com/t/xMGFi4sy

These are the settings in my `.ini` file:

```
[Costs]
DriverUnit=DBXDynalink
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxOracleDriver260.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxOracleDriver,Version=24.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverORACLE
LibraryName=dbxora.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlora.dylib
VendorLib=oci.dll
VendorLibWin64=oci.dll
VendorLibOsx=libociei.dylib
Database=ORACLE
User_Name=costs
Password=costs
MaxBlobSize=-1
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
RowsetSize=20
OSAuthentication=False
MultipleTransactions=False
TrimChar=False
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
OS Authentication=False
Multiple Transaction=False
Trim Char=False
Decimal Separator=,
```

Comment: Have you checked before you do `sqlConexao.Connected:=True` if the connection object has all the properties set like written in your ini file ?

Comment: From what I verified this is correct.

Comment: When you have done as the error message suggests (add DBXDynalink  to the uses) has anything changed ?.

Comment: DBXDynalink was added still giving the error.